# Location of static pointed memory

Tags: c, pointers

I read that pointers passed by malloc() & calloc() get allocated memory dynamically from the heap.

```
char *Name="Ann";
```

1. In this case, is the static string {'A','n','n','\0'} also stored in the heap?
2. Can I modify the string using the pointer?

Comment: In addition to Jerry's answer, it is a good idea to declare this differently, such that you will not be tempted to modify the string: `char const*Name="Ann";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, the string is allocated statically. (C99, §6.4.5/5)
2. Attempting to modify a string literal gives undefined behavior. (§6.4.5/6)